# Why dynamic selector does not work with directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, directive

I am generating chart dynamically with an ID, each chart has a resizable directive in which i pass the chartid and resize according to the container size. This works when the chart id is hardcoded. It does not work when i generate a unique id and select using the selector.

Here is my code,

**Working:**

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="CustomWidgetCtrl"  class="item"    style=" top: 50px; left: 110px; height: 500px; width: 500px; " ng-repeat="widget in dashboard.widgets"   data-identifier="{{widget.id}}" resizeable   >          
    <highchart id="chart1" config="widget.chartConfig"  ></highchart>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
routerApp.directive('resizeable', function() { 
  return { 
    restrict: 'A', 
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {       
      $(element).resizable({ 
        resize: function(event, ui) {     
         var chart = $('#chart1').highcharts();            
         height = ui.size.height - 100;
         width = ui.size.width - 40;
          chart.setSize(width, height, doAnimation = true);              
           jsPlumb.repaint(ui.helper); 
        }, 
        handles: "all"     
      }); 
    } 
  }; 
});
```

**Not Working:**

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="CustomWidgetCtrl"  class="item"    style=" top: 50px; left: 110px; height: 500px; width: 500px; " ng-repeat="widget in dashboard.widgets"   data-identifier="{{widget.id}}" resizeable   >          
    <div ng-controller="highchartCtrl"> 
        <highchart id="widget.id" config="widget.chartConfig"  ></highchart>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS with directive:**

```
 $scope.dashboard.widgets.push({
    name: $scope.chartConfig.title,
    id: "chart" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2),
    type:"All",
    chartTypes: $scope.chartTypes,
    data:$scope.data
  });

routerApp.directive('resizeable', function() { 
  return { 
    restrict: 'A', 
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {       
      $(element).resizable({ 
          resize: function(event, ui) {     
          var  widgetId = attrs.identifier;     
          var chart = $('#chart'+widgetId).highcharts();            
          height = ui.size.height - 100;
         width = ui.size.width - 40;
          chart.setSize(width, height, doAnimation = true);          
           jsPlumb.repaint(ui.helper); 
        }, 
        handles: "all" 

      }); 
    } 
  }; 
});
```

In the above, widgetid is the randomly generated id and appending with the chart, but when i evaluate chart in cosole, it becomes undefined. Any idea?

Comment: where you use `resizeable` attribute in your html?

Comment: in first case `var chart = $('#chart').highcharts();` is typo and should be `var chart = $('#chart1').highcharts();` or you realy use _chart_ as id?

Comment: I think you are looking for `id="{{widget.id}}"`. The `id` attribute will not interpolate the value on its own.

Comment: @DRobinson Actually no, because i can see the generated id inside the resizeable directive when i debug

Comment: I was talking about on the `highchart` element, not the `resizable` element. `id="widget.id"` will not give you the expected results.

Comment: yes got it corrected,it was a silly mistake. thanks guys, robinson post as an answer i will mark it